# Frame for grid-tables in Markdown

Tags: markdown, datagridtablestyle

I want to use grid tables in my Markdown document:

```
+---------------------+------------+
| **Property**        | **Earth**  |
+=============+=======+============+
|             | min   | *-89.2* °C |
| Temperature +-------+------------+
| 1961-1990   | mean  | *14* °C    |
|             +-------+------------+
|             | min   | *56.7* °C  |
+-------------+-------+------------+
```

I use pandoc for generate documentation, but, on GitHub it looks like:

```
+=============+=======+============+ | | min | -89.2 °C | | Temperature +-------+------------+ | 1961-1990 | mean | 14 °C | | +-------+------------+ | | min | 56.7 °C | +-------------+-------+------------+
```

I want to see it nice on github with the bold and italic formatting handled.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: GitHub defines the table syntax they support in there [spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-). That corresponds with Pandoc's [pipe tables](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-pipe_tables). If you want GitHub to render your tables, you need to use that syntax instead. Unfortunately, that means you cannot span rows or columns as that feature is not supported in this table format.